# Error on heroku production but not local

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

For some reason I'm getting an issue on production with the same code on heroku. would there be an explanation for this? Here's the heroku logs:

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 183ms
2012-07-07T23:15:41+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-07-07T23:15:41+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (gmaps4rails.css isn't precompiled):
2012-0
7-07T23:15:41+00:00 app[web.1]:     8:     = javascript_include_tag "application"
2012-07-07T23:15:41+00:00 app[web.1]:     9:     = csrf_meta_tags
2012-07-07T23:15:41+00:00 app[web.1]:     10:     = render 'layouts/shim'
2012-07-07T23:15:41+00:00 app[web.1]:     11:     = stylesheet_link_tag "gmaps4rails"
2012-07-07T23:15:41+00:00 app[web.1]:     12: 
2012-07-07T23:15:41+00:00 app[web.1]:     13:     %meta{ :name => "viewport", :content => "width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"}
2012-07-07T23:15:41+00:00 app[web.1]:     14:   %body
2012-07-07T23:15:41+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/layouts/application.html.haml:11:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_haml__610548992894307187_47414440'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your gmaps4rails css doesnt exist, make sure that you either precompile it locally and commit it into the repo or remove all of your public/css files that will force heroku to compile the stylesheets for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to config/production.rb

```
config.assets.precompile += %w( gmaps4rails.css )
```